# getting the x value for the maximum y value

Tags: r, max

I want to extract from a data set the addition, maximum, and average value of a variable (y) jointly with the maximum value of x. I also want to get the x value at maximum y value but I am not able to do so. Tried the max function but gives me an error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
AUC<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) sum(d$y))
max.y<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) max(d$y))
max.x<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) max(d$x))
auc.mean<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) mean(d$y))
x.ymax<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) 
max(data_example, data_example$x, select="y"))

data.final<-cbind(AUC,max.y,max.x, auc.mean, x.ymax)
```

Here I uploaded the data for reproduce the example:

http://www.filedropper.com/dataexample_1

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Something like `d$x[which.max(d$y)]` should do it.

Comment: Yes! that worked perfect. Thanks a lot.